# Part-of-speech without Python

Tags: r, nlp, pos-tagger, treetagger, french

I am trying to do tagging of a *french text*, but `TreeTagger` needs `Python` which is impossible to install on my PC at work. For security reasons, it is impossible to install other programs (only `R`).

Is it possible to use `R` code for tagging which does not require neither `java` nor `Python`?

Comment: Check out the [CRAN taskviews](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/) for R packages by subject type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this moment there are no French POS-taggers implemented in R.

Comment: Ok ,thank you. Is it possible to use Pos tagger (http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tagger.shtml) in R ?

Comment: Yes but you need Java.  See the R package coreNLP at https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/coreNLP/index.html.  It is a wrapper for the Stanford CoreNLP Java library.